# What is IPC_EXCL short for?

Tags: c, linux

I am really curious about the full name of the flag IPC_EXCL when I uses function shmget in Linux. I know it is used with IPC_CREAT to ensure failure if the shared memory segment already exists. Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess "exclusive"

Comment: *"InterProcess Communication - Exclusive"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hulk's guess in the comments on the question is correct: "EXCL" is an abbreviation of "exclusive".  This is not apparent from the specification of IPC_EXCL itself (quoting https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_ipc.h.html):

> IPC_EXCL
> Fail if key exists.

...  but if you know that the flag was named by analogy with the `open(2)` flag `O_EXCL`, then it *is* apparent from the specification of *that* flag (quoting https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html):

> O_EXCL
> Exclusive use flag.

Answer (score 4):

It stands for *exclusive*. `IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL` mirrors `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` (used with `open`)  in that that it ensures that the calling thread either becomes an exclusive creator of the IPC (inter-process communication) object (or file) or the function fails with `EEXIST`.